# Entity Framework + Life Time + StructureMap + Unit Of Work + Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, structuremap, unit-of-work

I have a **windows service (or a Windows Forms)** and when a timer is elapsed, my service completes some tasks.

I don't want to use just **one Entity Framework context** as long as my app is running.

I saw **session factory in NHibernate** samples. Is there any thing like that for **EF**?

Here is how I use **EF** + **StructureMap** in my **ASP.NET or MVC** apps:

*Application Start:*

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(Function(config) config.For(Of IUnitOfWork).HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped.Use(Of UnitOfWork)())
```

*End Request:*

```
ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()
```

My **UnitOfWork** is Started **per web request**, and is **disposed** after request is ended.

In my **Win App scenario**, **UoW** should start when the timer is elapsed and disposed after my job is complete and **I don't want to handle it myself.**

*How can I achieve something like this in a windows form app?*

If I register my UoW using : `HybridHttprThreadLocalScoped` There is just **one UoW per thread** and if I **dispose** it, **it's gone**.

***EDIT:***

I have my **repositories + services** in a **dll** and I want to use them in **both web or win apps**, and because of that I used `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped`.

***Update 2:***

Here is my **Repository**:

```
Public Class ProductRepository

    Private ReadOnly _databaseFactory As DataAccess.IDatabaseFactory

    Public Sub New(ByVal databaseFactory As DataAccess.IDatabaseFactory)
        _databaseFactory = databaseFactory
    End Sub

    Public Function GetById(ByVal id As Integer) As Product
        Return (From item In _databaseFactory.GetDataContext.Products Where item.ProductId = id).FirstOrDefault
    End Function

End Class
```

and here is my **Service**:

```
Public Class ProductService

    Private ReadOnly _Repository As ProductRepository

    Public Sub New(ByVal repository As ProductRepository)
        _Repository = repository
    End Sub

    Public Function GetById(ByVal id As Integer) As Product
        Return _Repository.GetById(id)
    End Function

End Class
```

And I'm using **StructureMap**. StructureMap takes car of my **DatabaseFactory** and **UoW lifetime** in **web** scenarios. But I have no idea what to do in **win apps**. I can manage lifetime of UoW **myself**, but I'm searching for a way so StructureMap would **handle it for me** as it handles the lifetime in web apps.

Comment: Afshin I have similar problem like yours. Can you please share your final solution ?

Comment: @shaahin: my current solution is not perfect. I'll try to add it to this post asap. In web apps, start and end of the request is signaled by the framework but In windows apps it's not like that, so i'm doing it  manually and kind of simulating it. for example:  on some button's click handler method (in win apps) I'm signaling starting and ending of a request to my own infrastructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.Net provides the infrastructure (essentially one httpcontext per request) for managing your objectcontext lifetime. There is (obviously) no similar thing in winforms. The way to manage the EF context will therefore highly depend on your application's architecture.

For example, if you have an MVP or MVVM-style application you can couple the lifetime of your context to the lifetime of a Presenter or ViewModel. Or you could go for an abstract concept of a 'user story', and couple the lifetime of your object context to that. It really depends.

For inspiration, [look at this article by Ayende](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) (it's about session management with NHibernate, but the concepts are the same. Think NHibernate Session == Entity Framework ObjectContext)

Comment: thanks for reply. I've read the article you mentioned. The problem is: In web apps, structuremap starts and disposes my UoW for each session. In win app, structure map starts one UoW per thread and if I manage it's life time and dispose it after my presenter is disposed, Uow is gone but the thread is still alive! I think I should look more into structuremap and as you said, it highly depends on my app's architecture.

Comment: @Afshin Gh I don't think the uow lifetime should be managed by the IoC container, it should be explicit (at least in a desktop app

Comment: Yes. I couldn't find any better approach. Looks like I have to manage it myself in win apps. I'll wait a little more for other answers. (And voted up your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Web applications are **stateless**, in contrast desktop applications are **stateful**. In web, objects are typically created per-requests and disposed of likewise. There are many reasons why it is done that way (like handling multiple requests and limited amount of memory etc.), this is why you have all the infrastructure ready for that. In desktop, you can store everything in the memory.

Therefore, in desktop application you will need to implement session management **by hand** (usually per business transaction).

UPDATE: [this post](http://peplowdown.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/repository-pattern-in-entity-framework-4-0/) has relevant code on sessions

Comment: I'm completely aware of differences between web and win apps. In NHibernate you have Session Factory. What's equal of that in EF?

Comment: @Afshin Gh sorry for a pointless answer. Maybe you can see this post then? http://peplowdown.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/repository-pattern-in-entity-framework-4-0/   The guy creates session factory and sessions in there with EF.

Comment: The article you linked, is not exactly what I was looking for but it is useful. I appreciate your help and I voted up you answer and I'll wait for others to vote and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework gives you "Context" which is a kind of Session with Scope of Unit Of Work within itself, all operations done for one Context remains in Scope of Context. And Entity Framework implements Unit Of Work pattern already. EF also implements identity map, so for one primary key, you will find only one object referenced everywhere in navigation property.

For Desktop Application, you have to only maintain one Context, that will be scope of all operations and it stores all operations in correct state till you call SaveChanges.

For Web Application, you can put your context in Session of ASP.NET, that may increase the load on server, but it might allow you to store changes for longer duration then just a single page.

> I don't want to use just one Entity Framework context as long as my app is running.

What is wrong with one context as long as app is running? Instead it is the correct way to do it. Keeping one context alive does not mean you are keeping connection to database alive. Database connections are opened and closed only while querying and saving changes.

If your app goes little out of balance and causes memory issues, best way would be to just allocate new context and refresh your UI, it will put all old context and its objects into garbage collector and your new context will serve you with lesser memory.

Comment: I don't like keeping my context alive as long as my win app is running. starting my UoW when i need it and closing it after job is done, looks better to me. but you are completely right and your answer is useful. voted it up.

Comment: The ObjectContext is not meant to be a long-lived object. It is not a best practice to keep it alive (a.o. because everything you query remains cached, so the longer it stays alive chances become bigger you get to look at stale data in multi-user environments)

Comment: @jeroenh, if you read my answer, I am not suggesting anyone to keep ObjectContext for longer time in multi user environment, for single user, it is best and the most preferred way to keep it long lived because you will be keeping your objects in memory anyway, to display to review and to edit.